# Google Forms Email Notifications based on response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am designing a questionnaire that requires respondents to input their name and a company code that is specific to their employer. I would like to have a script so that a different company will get an email notification depending on which company code is specified. I created a Google Sheet in the Form that lists company codes, corresponding emails, and messages.

I have found a script that does this but I have to tailor it to my own form. Can anyone do this or has a better code?

Link to Demo Form: [Here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XzoKbzEYqsSL4RCPsIeKrUjiulByETer7GElczbvMyU/edit?usp=sharing)

Link to demo spreadsheet: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JHwqTYPUYoHb57NVfT4zmttydgEbGgyaqWNDkLyYKjY/edit?usp=sharing)

```html
//using the obtained settings to set up email info
function onOpen(e) {
   FormApp.getUi().createMenu('Authorizer').addItem('Authorize', 'authorize').addToUi();
      
 }

//Easily authorize script to run from Form Editor interface
function authorize(){

var respEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
MailApp.sendEmail(respEmail,"Form Authorizer", "Your form has now been authorized to send you emails");

}

function setSettings(e){

  
  var response = e.response; 
  var settings = getSettings();
  var emailSubject = settings[1][2];
  var emailMsg = settings[1][3];
  var formCompany = getResponse(response,"Company Code");
  var formName = getResponse(response,"Name");
  var emailAddr;
  var companycode;
  
  //loop through and grab the selected school from the Settings spreadsheet.
  for (i in settings){
    if (settings[i][0] === formcompanycode){
      
      school = settings[i][0];
      emailAddr = settings[i][1];    
        } 
       
  }

//build email and send to email send function
emailMsg = emailMsg + '\n' + 'Company Code: ' + formSchool +  '\n' + 'Name: ' + formName;
mailSendSimple(emailAddr,emailSubject,emailMsg);

 }
//function to find the selected company code. 
function getResponse(response,formItem){ 

  var selected;  
  //loop through the form response to find the company code 
  for (var i = 0; i < response.getItemResponses().length; i++){  
 if (formItem == response.getItemResponses()[i].getItem().getTitle()){
    selected = response.getItemResponses()[i].getResponse();       
   }  
  }
  return selected;
} 
 //grabbing general settings from spreadsheet sheet Settings
function getSettings() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ssID = form.getDestinationId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn);
  var values = range.getValues();
  return values;  
}


//function to send out mail
function mailSendSimple(emailAddr,emailSub, emailMsg){
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddr,emailSub, emailMsg); //{cc: ccUser}
  
}
```

Comment: Did you already tried to adapt the code that you found? What problems did you faced?

Comment: I've replaced "school" and "student" that I found in the code with the correlating value from my own settings. It still hasn't been working where it will send an email even after I've authorized it.

Comment: Did you already created the on form submit installable trigger?

Comment: I have already added a Getsettings>from form>on form submit trigger. I have a feeling There is some inconsistency between the code itself and what it's trying to pull from form but I'm not too sure how to code that fix myself.

Comment: Add the details that you shared in the last comments to the question. Also create a demo form/spreadsheet share them with anyone with the link and add the links to the question too.

Comment: I updated the snippet with the code I had edited and the links to a copy of the form and spreadsheet if that helps.

Comment: I suggest to change the sharing settings to view only. Otherwise there is a risk that people accessing at different times see different things.

Comment: Is the formcompanycode line the only thing that needs to be revised?

Comment: No. That is why I added two sections to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35320947/1595451). If an answer is not clear you could request clarifications adding a comment to the related answer.

Comment: I suggested an edit to add a mention that your script is bounded to a Google Form but it was rejected by splited votes (2 Approved Vs 3 Rejected). Consider add yourself that mention.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer

In `formcompanycode` used in the line

```
if (settings[i][0] === formcompanycode){
```

is not defined.

## Remarks

See [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas). The technique described there will help you to debug your code and find other errors.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful.